# extra straight lines on google linecharts

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I've written some `js` code to draw `google visualization linecharts` from `json` input.

The line charts are drawn with extra straight lines touching the extremes of the curved lines as shown in the below image.

**Current line graph :**

[image: Line charts with extra straight lines]

**To-be line graph without straight lines:**

[image: To-be line graph without straight lines]
**Have written below js code :**

```
google.charts.load('current', {

    callback : function() {

        drawChart();

        $(window).resize(drawChart);

    },

    packages : [ 'corechart' ]

});

function drawChart() {

    var json = jsonData[0];

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('datetime',json[0].splunkConfig.parameter1);
    data.addColumn('number', json[0].splunkConfig.parameter2);
    data.addColumn('number', json[0].splunkConfig.parameter3);


    $.each(json[0].splunkConfigs, function(i, splunkConfigs) {
        var result = [];
        data.addRow([ new Date(splunkConfigs.parameter1),
                      Number(splunkConfigs.parameter2), Number(splunkConfigs.parameter3) ]);
    });

    var options = {
        hAxis : {
            title : 'Time',
            textStyle : {
                color : '#01579b',
                fontSize : 20,
                fontName : 'Arial',
                bold : true,
                italic : true
            },
            titleTextStyle : {
                color : '#01579b',
                fontSize : 16,
                fontName : 'Arial',
                bold : false,
                italic : true
            }
        },
        vAxis : {
            title : 'Count',
            textStyle : {
                color : '#1a237e',
                fontSize : 24,
                bold : true
            },
            titleTextStyle : {
                color : '#1a237e',
                fontSize : 24,
                bold : true
            }
        },
        colors : [ '#a52714', '#097138' ],
        title : 'Sample json line chart'
    };

    // ...etc. Rest of your code comes here, or is called from here.
    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document
            .getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, {
        width : 1400,
        height : 650
    });

}
```

**Sample data :**

```
[[{"splunkConfig":{"id":0,"parameter1":"_time","parameter2":"Peak (second)","parameter3":"TPS (ave/min)","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},"splunkConfigs":[{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 07:59:00","parameter2":"250","parameter3":"198.575000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:00:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"208.000000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:01:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"232.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:02:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"232.516667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:03:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"227.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:04:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"219.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:05:00","parameter2":"311","parameter3":"233.533333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:06:00","parameter2":"280","parameter3":"222.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:07:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"216.216667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:08:00","parameter2":"258","parameter3":"208.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:09:00","parameter2":"269","parameter3":"214.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:10:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"208.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:11:00","parameter2":"272","parameter3":"219.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:12:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"222.850000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:13:00","parameter2":"276","parameter3":"221.133333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:14:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"228.066667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:15:00","parameter2":"299","parameter3":"231.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:16:00","parameter2":"279","parameter3":"216.250000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:17:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"215.966667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:18:00","parameter2":"291","parameter3":"227.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:19:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"231.916667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:20:00","parameter2":"285","parameter3":"226.650000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:21:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"218.733333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:22:00","parameter2":"325","parameter3":"218.566667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:23:00","parameter2":"343","parameter3":"234.700000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:24:00","parameter2":"373","parameter3":"246.416667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:25:00","parameter2":"332","parameter3":"224.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:26:00","parameter2":"328","parameter3":"237.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:27:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"228.616667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:28:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"222.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:29:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"216.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:30:00","parameter2":"268","parameter3":"218.866667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:31:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"224.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:32:00","parameter2":"346","parameter3":"244.800000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:33:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.683333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:34:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"238.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:35:00","parameter2":"289","parameter3":"210.150000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:36:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"229.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:37:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"235.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:38:00","parameter2":"304","parameter3":"243.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:39:00","parameter2":"320","parameter3":"241.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:40:00","parameter2":"282","parameter3":"224.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:41:00","parameter2":"290","parameter3":"225.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:42:00","parameter2":"337","parameter3":"251.183333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:43:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.266667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:44:00","parameter2":"303","parameter3":"230.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:45:00","parameter2":"317","parameter3":"233.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:46:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"227.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:47:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"225.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:48:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"214.233333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:49:00","parameter2":"323","parameter3":"227.883333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:50:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"236.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:51:00","parameter2":"306","parameter3":"240.933333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:52:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"233.750000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:53:00","parameter2":"324","parameter3":"244.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:54:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"250.433333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:55:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"247.016667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:56:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"221.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:57:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"239.300000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:58:00","parameter2":"266","parameter3":"222.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:59:00","parameter2":"260","parameter3":"199.400000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 07:59:00","parameter2":"250","parameter3":"198.575000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:00:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"208.000000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:01:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"232.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:02:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"232.516667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:03:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"227.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:04:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"219.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:05:00","parameter2":"311","parameter3":"233.533333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:06:00","parameter2":"280","parameter3":"222.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:07:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"216.216667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:08:00","parameter2":"258","parameter3":"208.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:09:00","parameter2":"269","parameter3":"214.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:10:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"208.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:11:00","parameter2":"272","parameter3":"219.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:12:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"222.850000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:13:00","parameter2":"276","parameter3":"221.133333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:14:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"228.066667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:15:00","parameter2":"299","parameter3":"231.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:16:00","parameter2":"279","parameter3":"216.250000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:17:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"215.966667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:18:00","parameter2":"291","parameter3":"227.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:19:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"231.916667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:20:00","parameter2":"285","parameter3":"226.650000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:21:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"218.733333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:22:00","parameter2":"325","parameter3":"218.566667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:23:00","parameter2":"343","parameter3":"234.700000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:24:00","parameter2":"373","parameter3":"246.416667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:25:00","parameter2":"332","parameter3":"224.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:26:00","parameter2":"328","parameter3":"237.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:27:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"228.616667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:28:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"222.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:29:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"216.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:30:00","parameter2":"268","parameter3":"218.866667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:31:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"224.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:32:00","parameter2":"346","parameter3":"244.800000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:33:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.683333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:34:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"238.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:35:00","parameter2":"289","parameter3":"210.150000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:36:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"229.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:37:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"235.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:38:00","parameter2":"304","parameter3":"243.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:39:00","parameter2":"320","parameter3":"241.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:40:00","parameter2":"282","parameter3":"224.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:41:00","parameter2":"290","parameter3":"225.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:42:00","parameter2":"337","parameter3":"251.183333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:43:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.266667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:44:00","parameter2":"303","parameter3":"230.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:45:00","parameter2":"317","parameter3":"233.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:46:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"227.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:47:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"225.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:48:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"214.233333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:49:00","parameter2":"323","parameter3":"227.883333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:50:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"236.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:51:00","parameter2":"306","parameter3":"240.933333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:52:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"233.750000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:53:00","parameter2":"324","parameter3":"244.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:54:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"250.433333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:55:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"247.016667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:56:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"221.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:57:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"239.300000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:58:00","parameter2":"266","parameter3":"222.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:59:00","parameter2":"260","parameter3":"199.400000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 07:59:00","parameter2":"250","parameter3":"198.575000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:00:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"208.000000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:01:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"232.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:02:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"232.516667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:03:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"227.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:04:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"219.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:05:00","parameter2":"311","parameter3":"233.533333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:06:00","parameter2":"280","parameter3":"222.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:07:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"216.216667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:08:00","parameter2":"258","parameter3":"208.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:09:00","parameter2":"269","parameter3":"214.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:10:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"208.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:11:00","parameter2":"272","parameter3":"219.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:12:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"222.850000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:13:00","parameter2":"276","parameter3":"221.133333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:14:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"228.066667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:15:00","parameter2":"299","parameter3":"231.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:16:00","parameter2":"279","parameter3":"216.250000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:17:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"215.966667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:18:00","parameter2":"291","parameter3":"227.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:19:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"231.916667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:20:00","parameter2":"285","parameter3":"226.650000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:21:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"218.733333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:22:00","parameter2":"325","parameter3":"218.566667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:23:00","parameter2":"343","parameter3":"234.700000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:24:00","parameter2":"373","parameter3":"246.416667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:25:00","parameter2":"332","parameter3":"224.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:26:00","parameter2":"328","parameter3":"237.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:27:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"228.616667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:28:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"222.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:29:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"216.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:30:00","parameter2":"268","parameter3":"218.866667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:31:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"224.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:32:00","parameter2":"346","parameter3":"244.800000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:33:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.683333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:34:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"238.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:35:00","parameter2":"289","parameter3":"210.150000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:36:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"229.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:37:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"235.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:38:00","parameter2":"304","parameter3":"243.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:39:00","parameter2":"320","parameter3":"241.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:40:00","parameter2":"282","parameter3":"224.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:41:00","parameter2":"290","parameter3":"225.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:42:00","parameter2":"337","parameter3":"251.183333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:43:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.266667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:44:00","parameter2":"303","parameter3":"230.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:45:00","parameter2":"317","parameter3":"233.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:46:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"227.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:47:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"225.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:48:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"214.233333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:49:00","parameter2":"323","parameter3":"227.883333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:50:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"236.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:51:00","parameter2":"306","parameter3":"240.933333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:52:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"233.750000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:53:00","parameter2":"324","parameter3":"244.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:54:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"250.433333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:55:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"247.016667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:56:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"221.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:57:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"239.300000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:58:00","parameter2":"266","parameter3":"222.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:59:00","parameter2":"260","parameter3":"199.400000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null}],"countOfParams":3}]]
```

Have tried with multiple `javascript datetime` options but none of them worked.. :(

If you could help/guide me in removing the straight lines, it would be really great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need to sort the data before drawing...

```
// sort data before drawing
data.sort([{column: 0}]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback : function() {
    drawChart();
    $(window).resize(drawChart);
  },
  packages : [ 'corechart' ]
});

function drawChart() {
  var json = [[{"splunkConfig":{"id":0,"parameter1":"_time","parameter2":"Peak (second)","parameter3":"TPS (ave/min)","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},"splunkConfigs":[{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 07:59:00","parameter2":"250","parameter3":"198.575000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:00:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"208.000000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:01:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"232.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:02:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"232.516667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:03:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"227.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:04:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"219.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:05:00","parameter2":"311","parameter3":"233.533333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:06:00","parameter2":"280","parameter3":"222.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:07:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"216.216667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:08:00","parameter2":"258","parameter3":"208.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:09:00","parameter2":"269","parameter3":"214.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:10:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"208.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:11:00","parameter2":"272","parameter3":"219.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:12:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"222.850000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:13:00","parameter2":"276","parameter3":"221.133333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:14:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"228.066667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:15:00","parameter2":"299","parameter3":"231.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:16:00","parameter2":"279","parameter3":"216.250000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:17:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"215.966667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:18:00","parameter2":"291","parameter3":"227.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:19:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"231.916667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:20:00","parameter2":"285","parameter3":"226.650000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:21:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"218.733333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:22:00","parameter2":"325","parameter3":"218.566667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:23:00","parameter2":"343","parameter3":"234.700000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:24:00","parameter2":"373","parameter3":"246.416667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:25:00","parameter2":"332","parameter3":"224.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:26:00","parameter2":"328","parameter3":"237.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:27:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"228.616667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:28:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"222.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:29:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"216.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:30:00","parameter2":"268","parameter3":"218.866667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:31:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"224.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:32:00","parameter2":"346","parameter3":"244.800000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:33:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.683333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:34:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"238.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:35:00","parameter2":"289","parameter3":"210.150000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:36:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"229.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:37:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"235.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:38:00","parameter2":"304","parameter3":"243.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:39:00","parameter2":"320","parameter3":"241.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:40:00","parameter2":"282","parameter3":"224.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:41:00","parameter2":"290","parameter3":"225.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:42:00","parameter2":"337","parameter3":"251.183333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:43:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.266667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:44:00","parameter2":"303","parameter3":"230.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:45:00","parameter2":"317","parameter3":"233.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:46:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"227.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:47:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"225.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:48:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"214.233333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:49:00","parameter2":"323","parameter3":"227.883333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:50:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"236.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:51:00","parameter2":"306","parameter3":"240.933333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:52:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"233.750000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:53:00","parameter2":"324","parameter3":"244.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:54:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"250.433333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:55:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"247.016667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:56:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"221.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:57:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"239.300000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:58:00","parameter2":"266","parameter3":"222.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:59:00","parameter2":"260","parameter3":"199.400000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 07:59:00","parameter2":"250","parameter3":"198.575000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:00:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"208.000000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:01:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"232.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:02:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"232.516667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:03:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"227.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:04:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"219.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:05:00","parameter2":"311","parameter3":"233.533333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:06:00","parameter2":"280","parameter3":"222.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:07:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"216.216667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:08:00","parameter2":"258","parameter3":"208.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:09:00","parameter2":"269","parameter3":"214.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:10:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"208.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:11:00","parameter2":"272","parameter3":"219.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:12:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"222.850000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:13:00","parameter2":"276","parameter3":"221.133333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:14:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"228.066667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:15:00","parameter2":"299","parameter3":"231.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:16:00","parameter2":"279","parameter3":"216.250000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:17:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"215.966667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:18:00","parameter2":"291","parameter3":"227.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:19:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"231.916667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:20:00","parameter2":"285","parameter3":"226.650000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:21:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"218.733333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:22:00","parameter2":"325","parameter3":"218.566667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:23:00","parameter2":"343","parameter3":"234.700000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:24:00","parameter2":"373","parameter3":"246.416667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:25:00","parameter2":"332","parameter3":"224.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:26:00","parameter2":"328","parameter3":"237.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:27:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"228.616667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:28:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"222.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:29:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"216.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:30:00","parameter2":"268","parameter3":"218.866667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:31:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"224.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:32:00","parameter2":"346","parameter3":"244.800000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:33:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.683333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:34:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"238.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:35:00","parameter2":"289","parameter3":"210.150000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:36:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"229.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:37:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"235.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:38:00","parameter2":"304","parameter3":"243.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:39:00","parameter2":"320","parameter3":"241.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:40:00","parameter2":"282","parameter3":"224.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:41:00","parameter2":"290","parameter3":"225.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:42:00","parameter2":"337","parameter3":"251.183333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:43:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.266667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:44:00","parameter2":"303","parameter3":"230.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:45:00","parameter2":"317","parameter3":"233.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:46:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"227.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:47:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"225.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:48:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"214.233333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:49:00","parameter2":"323","parameter3":"227.883333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:50:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"236.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:51:00","parameter2":"306","parameter3":"240.933333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:52:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"233.750000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:53:00","parameter2":"324","parameter3":"244.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:54:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"250.433333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:55:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"247.016667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:56:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"221.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:57:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"239.300000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:58:00","parameter2":"266","parameter3":"222.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:59:00","parameter2":"260","parameter3":"199.400000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 07:59:00","parameter2":"250","parameter3":"198.575000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:00:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"208.000000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:01:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"232.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:02:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"232.516667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:03:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"227.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:04:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"219.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:05:00","parameter2":"311","parameter3":"233.533333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:06:00","parameter2":"280","parameter3":"222.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:07:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"216.216667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:08:00","parameter2":"258","parameter3":"208.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:09:00","parameter2":"269","parameter3":"214.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:10:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"208.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:11:00","parameter2":"272","parameter3":"219.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:12:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"222.850000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:13:00","parameter2":"276","parameter3":"221.133333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:14:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"228.066667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:15:00","parameter2":"299","parameter3":"231.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:16:00","parameter2":"279","parameter3":"216.250000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:17:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"215.966667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:18:00","parameter2":"291","parameter3":"227.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:19:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"231.916667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:20:00","parameter2":"285","parameter3":"226.650000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:21:00","parameter2":"281","parameter3":"218.733333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:22:00","parameter2":"325","parameter3":"218.566667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:23:00","parameter2":"343","parameter3":"234.700000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:24:00","parameter2":"373","parameter3":"246.416667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:25:00","parameter2":"332","parameter3":"224.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:26:00","parameter2":"328","parameter3":"237.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:27:00","parameter2":"305","parameter3":"228.616667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:28:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"222.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:29:00","parameter2":"274","parameter3":"216.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:30:00","parameter2":"268","parameter3":"218.866667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:31:00","parameter2":"283","parameter3":"224.033333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:32:00","parameter2":"346","parameter3":"244.800000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:33:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.683333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:34:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"238.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:35:00","parameter2":"289","parameter3":"210.150000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:36:00","parameter2":"288","parameter3":"229.583333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:37:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"235.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:38:00","parameter2":"304","parameter3":"243.483333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:39:00","parameter2":"320","parameter3":"241.950000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:40:00","parameter2":"282","parameter3":"224.116667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:41:00","parameter2":"290","parameter3":"225.466667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:42:00","parameter2":"337","parameter3":"251.183333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:43:00","parameter2":"294","parameter3":"233.266667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:44:00","parameter2":"303","parameter3":"230.350000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:45:00","parameter2":"317","parameter3":"233.550000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:46:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"227.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:47:00","parameter2":"298","parameter3":"225.816667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:48:00","parameter2":"259","parameter3":"214.233333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:49:00","parameter2":"323","parameter3":"227.883333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:50:00","parameter2":"284","parameter3":"236.366667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:51:00","parameter2":"306","parameter3":"240.933333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:52:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"233.750000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:53:00","parameter2":"324","parameter3":"244.383333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:54:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"250.433333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:55:00","parameter2":"301","parameter3":"247.016667","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:56:00","parameter2":"293","parameter3":"221.983333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:57:00","parameter2":"308","parameter3":"239.300000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:58:00","parameter2":"266","parameter3":"222.833333","parameter4":null,"checklists":null},{"id":0,"parameter1":"2017-04-14 08:59:00","parameter2":"260","parameter3":"199.400000","parameter4":null,"checklists":null}],"countOfParams":3}]][0];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime',json[0].splunkConfig.parameter1);
  data.addColumn('number', json[0].splunkConfig.parameter2);
  data.addColumn('number', json[0].splunkConfig.parameter3);

  $.each(json[0].splunkConfigs, function(i, splunkConfigs) {
    var result = [];
    data.addRow([
      new Date(splunkConfigs.parameter1),
      Number(splunkConfigs.parameter2),
      Number(splunkConfigs.parameter3)
    ]);
  });

  // sort data before drawing
  data.sort([{column: 0}]);

  var options = {
      hAxis : {
          title : 'Time',
          textStyle : {
              color : '#01579b',
              fontSize : 20,
              fontName : 'Arial',
              bold : true,
              italic : true
          },
          titleTextStyle : {
              color : '#01579b',
              fontSize : 16,
              fontName : 'Arial',
              bold : false,
              italic : true
          }
      },
      vAxis : {
          title : 'Count',
          textStyle : {
              color : '#1a237e',
              fontSize : 24,
              bold : true
          },
          titleTextStyle : {
              color : '#1a237e',
              fontSize : 24,
              bold : true
          }
      },
      colors : [ '#a52714', '#097138' ],
      title : 'Sample json line chart'
  };

  // ...etc. Rest of your code comes here, or is called from here.
  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document
          .getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, {
      width : 1400,
      height : 650
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Many Thanks, actually I got the issue. There were duplicates in the data. So, I had to filter them. Many Thanks for your answer. Yours works too..!!!